# How to formulate nuclear norm minimisation (of a matrix) as an SDP?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, semidefinite-programming

It is pretty well-known that the minimisation of the nuclear norm (sum of all singular values) is closely related to semidefinite programming.

However, I struggle to find a way to rewrite the problem "minimise $\|A\|_{\ast},$ the nuclear norm, subject to $A \in \mathcal A$" into the form "minimise $f(B)$ subject to $B \geq 0, g(B) \in \mathcal A$" where $f,g$  are linear.

Does anyone have a reference or know a brief answer?

Comment: I believe this is the classic reference https://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/pubs/files/RechtFazelParrilo-GuaranteedMinimumRankSolutionsOfLinearMatrixEquationsViaNuclearNormMinimization-SIAM.pdf

Comment: https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html#singular-value-optimization